# How to initialize solver variable in julia

Tags: variables, initialization, julia

I am trying to initialize an inventory variable in Julia using JuMP. In the following code you can see my try but unfortunately it is somehow not working correctly. I don't get an error when I execute the code but in my solution I see that the initial inventory differs from my input data.

`inventory_0` is a Dictionary: `Dict{String,Dict{String,Int64}}`

What am I doing wrong?

I create and try to initialize the variable like this:

```
 @variable(m, inventory[p = periods, i = origin_stations, k = container_types] >= 0, Int)

for i in origin_stations
    for k in container_types
        inventory["P1",i,k] == inventory_0[i][k]
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi, which optimization package are you using? JuMP? You should change the title accordingly. "A variable" here specifically means a solver variable, not a Julia variable, so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I made the change. Yes, I am using JuMP.

Comment: Ok, cool. Now please also write into the question text that you're using JuMP -- comments are considered ephemeral. And to make it answerable, you should also specify the result you want, and explain what you actually get -- as of yet, I fear the question will draw downvotes.

Comment: Oh, and maybe the error is that you're using `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment) -- but I have no idea whether that's actually true, since you don't write what results you get.

Comment: Agree with the above comment. That’s likely the issue but it’s unclear since the code can not be run.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Switchting from `==` to `=` I get an error when I exectue the code: 

MethodError: Cannot convert an object of type Int64 to an object of type VariableRef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by incorporating the initial inventory to the constraints. So the code looks like this:

```
for i in origin_stations
    for k in container_types
        @constraint(m, inventory["P1",i,k] == inventory_0[i][k])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it appears the issue is the use of == which does comparison vs the use of = which is for assignment. Try switching `inventory["P1",i,k] == inventory_0[i][k]` to

`inventory["P1",i,k] = inventory_0[i][k]`.

Comment: And if this doesn’t fix the issue, please try and post a reproducible example so we all have more tools to try and help you!